# Cauchy Schwarz Inequality and Quadrilaterals

Tags: graph-theory

I'm currently working on a problem from Bondy & Murty. The question is below.

Show if the number of edges $m > \frac{1} {4}n (\sqrt{4n-3} + 1)$, $G$ contains a quadrilateral.

I know that I need to use that if $\sum \limits_v {d(v) \choose 2} > {n \choose 2}$ then the graph contains a quadrilateral, but it also says to use the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality and I'm not sure which form that means (especially in terms of a graph). Any explanation of that would be much appreciated.

I'm not sure where to start, but I feel like that interpretation of the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality will help me get an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $m > \frac{1}{4}n(\sqrt{4n-3}+1)$. We will show that $G$ contains a quadrilateral. Let $d_i$ denote the degree of vertex $i$, and let $D$ be the degree sequence of $G$, arranged in nonincreasing order: $D = (d_1, d_2, \dots, d_n)$. By the *Handshake Lemma*, we have $\sum_{i=1}^n d_i = 2m > \frac{1}{2}n(\sqrt{4n-3}+1)$. Then by *Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality,*

\begin{align*}
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n d_i^2\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n 1\right) &\geq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n d_i\right)^2 \\
n\left(\sum_{i=1}^n d_i^2\right) &\geq \frac{1}{4}n^2(4n-3)+n^2 \\
\sum_{i=1}^n d_i^2 &\geq \frac{1}{4}(4n-3)+n \\
&= n^2.
\end{align*}

Thus, by the *pigeonhole principle*, there must exist two vertices $u$ and $v$ such that $d_u^2 + d_v^2 \geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n d_i^2 \geq n$. Let $N_u$ and $N_v$ denote the neighbors of $u$ and $v$, respectively. Since $u$ and $v$ have at least $n-2$ neighbors between them, $N_u \cap N_v$ must be nonempty. Let $w$ be a vertex in $N_u \cap N_v$. Then $u$, $v$, $w$, and any fourth vertex in $N_u \cup N_v$ form a quadrilateral in $G$. Therefore, $G$ contains a quadrilateral, as desired.